# mongodb get list of subdocuments that matched with list of values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

my document schema goes like this

```
_id: kkj33h2kjkjh32jk34
events: [
        {
          _id: k234j3lk4k2j3h4j3j4
        },
        {
          _id: k234j3lk4k2j3h4j3j4
        },
        {
        _id: k234j3lk4k2j3h4j3j4
         }
      ]
```

here is my query, I have a list of _ids of the subdocuments of events field and I need to get all the matched subdocuments as the response from the event field I have tried to use $in and many but failed can anyone suggest me how to do this

tried this

```
subarr=['fh576hgfu658uyg7h','k234j3lk4k2j3h4j3j4']
model.findOne({
                    clgid: req.query.clgid,
                    'events._id': {$in:subarr}
                },{"events.$":1});
```

but the problem with the above code is that it is fetching the first matching subdocument. but I need all the matching subdocuments.
suggest me the right way to do this query so that I get all the matched subdocuments that match from array

Comment: You are executing `findOne` method which will return only one document.

Comment: Yes i need matched subdocuments inside a document

Answer (score 0):

The issue of your query matching only the first subdocument is the use of `{"events.$":1}` in your projection.

I'm not sure what you are actually intending to do.
`{"events.$":1}` will limit to the first (sub)document matching your query, as per the [documentation of the `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_).
Maybe you're trying only to get the `_id` of the subdocuments and then, please try the following:

```
subarr=['fh576hgfu658uyg7h','k234j3lk4k2j3h4j3j4']
model.findOne({
    clgid: req.query.clgid,
    'events._id': {$in:subarr}
},{"events._id":1});
```